# Banach Space not reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. If $X$ is not Reflexive, does there exist $f\in X'$ such that there does not exist $x \in X$ with $f(x)=\|f\|\cdot\|x\|$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Actually, this is an "if and only if statement": a Banach space $X$ is reflexive if and only if every continuous linear functional achieves its maximum on the unit ball. This is called [James' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%27_theorem).